# django - custom error message for urlinput widget

Tags: python, django, widget, modelform

django 1.7
trying to customize the default client side validation message that gets fired on a model form.  Specifically the error message for urlinput widget (the default for a urlfield). This error appears to come from client side validation when the form is submitted.
[image: The target error message]

I want to change "Please enter a URL" to something else. I feel like I've looked everywhere but can't find it.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url type in Html5 will display required attribute message lilke this

```
Cross browser verbiage:
    Firefox: Please enter a URL.
    Chrome: Please enter a URL.
    IE: You must enter a valid URL
```

You can use `setcustomvalidity`

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This explains why i couldn't find anything combing django source.  Didnt think to checl html5 spec